# Changing the Colour of GNOME (GDM) Login Box on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: 18.04, login-screen, gdm

I changed the background to an image on my login screen.  No problem.  However, I want to change the user selection box from orange to something complimentary.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in Ubuntu 18.04 by default the login-screen uses `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file..

the Orange color `#dd4814` is from this portion

```
.login-dialog-user-list {
  spacing: 12px;
  padding: .2em;
  width: 23em; }
  .login-dialog-user-list:expanded .login-dialog-user-list-item:selected {
    background-color: #dd4814;
    color: #ffffff; }
  .login-dialog-user-list:expanded .login-dialog-user-list-item:logged-in {
    border-right: 2px solid #dd4814; }
```

you can edit the color according to your preferences in above field..

i have configured it to blue color

[image]