# Another ask for change Ubuntu 18.04 Orange color - it persists changing Gnome themes

Tags: gnome, themes, colors

I know there are lot of questions asking the same thing. Change the Ubuntu's default orange color.

Checking many questions/answers I was able to change in almost every place but not on the  search and menu bars and on the GDM login screen (the selection color there is still orange).

[image: Hi]

Maybe someone know where to change in these places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default Ubuntu 18.04 uses `/usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css` file for GDM Login and for user theme (gnome-shell)

this means, changing the contents in it will effect both GDM Login screen and user theme (gnome-shell) unless you configure both with other files.

So first take the backup of the file and then edit it,

```
sudo -H gedit /usr/share/gnome-shell/theme/ubuntu.css
```

for the changes you are looking for, search for this field and concentrate on the colors blue, green and red. Note that I have already edited the colors from default orange to blue, green and red.

```
.window-clone-border {
  border: 4px solid blue;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 0px 1px green; }

.window-caption {
  spacing: 25px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: red;
  border-radius: 8px;
  padding: 4px 12px; }
```

[image]

concentrate on text "magenta" in below field.

```
.workspace-thumbnail-indicator {
  border: 4px solid magenta;
  padding: 1px; }
```

[image]

Concentrate on text "cyan" in below field

```
#panel .panel-button:active, #panel .panel-button:overview, #panel .panel-button:focus, #panel .panel-button:checked {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.01);
  box-shadow: inset 0 -2px 0px cyan;
  color: white; }`
```

[image]

for login screen changes you are looking for refer to this post [Changing the Colour of GNOME (GDM) Login Box on Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/q/1124357/739431)

for the dot color on dock indicator, refer to this post
[How can I change the color of the marker on the dash that indicates an application is "up"?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1148171/739431)

[image]

you can replace the svg icon with your custom svg icon with the same name or you can define the custom icon path in the same .css file.

```
/* window close ubuntu image */
.window-close {
  background-image: url("ubuntu-close-window.svg");
}
```

below pic is a self explanatory.

[image]

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU very very much. It is exactly what I was looking for.