# How to change Ubuntu 21.04 Orange color? It persists even after changing GTK theme

Tags: 20.04, themes, gdm

I use gnome 3.38.5 on ubuntu 21.04.
My tweaks setting:
[image: tweaks setting]

basically i wanna change all the orange colour on ubuntu.
for example the border of this research form or those of the monitor preview on the right: [image: picture_1]

Comment: Change gnome-shell theme. If you want to edit the default shell theme only to change Orange  color let us know.

Comment: yes i basically want to change all orange to purple. can you help somehow ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/q/1194284/739431 this somehow guides you to identify orange colors.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have installed a theme and are using it for your desktop (i.e. your application windows). To use the same theme for “Gnome Shell” (i.e. the top bar, the dock, and the applications overview), do the following:

1. Go to extensions.gnome.org and install the [User Themes extension](https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/19/user-themes/)
2. Install Gnome Tweaks (listed for completeness, but you already have this).

   ```
   sudo apt install gnome-tweaks
   ```
3. Open Gnome Tweaks
4. Make sure the newly installed User Themes extension is active on the Extensions tab.
5. On the Appearance tab, select your desired (purple) theme for the Shell Theme.

Comment: I already installed and activated User Themes extension, but i can't chose any color, the appearance tab is the same as i posted before. I installed user theme from firefox, maybe this could be the issue. ad the shell is on default not gtk.

Comment: Where did you get this “Gtk-master” theme ?

Comment: emmh i dont remember exactly i think or from here : [link](https://github.com/GNOME/gtk) or from apt-get.

Comment: It's possible that this theme you are using is incomplete and does not include all the files needed to theme the  "shell". See if you have the same issue with another theme. For example, here is one that has a purple variant: [Yaru-Colors](https://github.com/Jannomag/Yaru-Colors).

Comment: yes i installed yaru-colors by snap and run the script for add the themes on tweaks. But this time the theme does not even appear  on the the theme list, should i try to change the repo or maybe is a tweak issue

Comment: ps. i use this: GDM 3.38.2.1, that is this thing : [link](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/xenial/man8/gdm3.8.html)

Comment: Don’t install the snap. Use `git clone` to download the files from the above URL. Then follow the installation instructions on the page: run `./install.sh` from the downloaded directory.